# !empty function giving weird value

Tags: php, isset

I have a php page where i have a hidden input as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selOption'+(i+1)+'" name="selOption'+(i+1)+'" value="0"/>
```

As  you can see that it has default value=0.
Now using Ajax i'm sending value of the above input along with some other hidden input type="hidden" to another page like:

```
    function showbtn(no,tid,tp){
        var v_qno = document.getElementById("QuestionID"+no).value;
        var v_secid = document.getElementById("sectionID"+no).value;
        var v_selans = 0;
            var v_vstatus = document.getElementById("visitStatus"+no).value;
            v_selans = document.getElementById("selOption"+no).value;

        var dataString = 'testId='+tid+'&secId='+v_secid+'&qNo='+ v_qno+'&selAns='+v_selans+'&vStat='+v_vstatus;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../member/updtBttnStatus.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                 //some code
                }
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is that in the updtBttnStatus.php page when i am using

```
if (!empty($_POST['selAns'])){
//some code here}
else{//}
```

to validate the value it goes to else part of the if loop whereas it should not be so because default value=0 being set in the first page.

Please help me as to what is that i am missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value of alert( v_selans ); coming?

Comment: _“Please help me as to what is that i am missing”_ – the explanation of how `empty` works in the manual …?

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't use `empty()` on a `0`. You'll get a false positive because in your case `0` is a valid value.

Quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

As an alternative, use `isset()` in your if block instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['selAns']) && $_POST['selAns'] !== '') {
    echo 'hi';
}
```